# collect intermediate data with streams

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Hi need to read some xml file sections to collect some data and make some grouping based on a key. I have tried to do it in a one shot operation using java 8 streams, but i am finding it difficult to return intermediate and grouping data together. This is what i have so far

```
<air:AirPricePointList>
    <air:AirPricePoint Key="5ScAI+BAAA" TotalPrice="" BasePrice="" ApproximateTotalPrice="" ApproximateBasePrice="" EquivalentBasePrice="" Taxes="" ApproximateTaxes="">
        <air:AirPricingInfo Key="" TotalPrice="" BasePrice="600.00" lasticketingTime="" PlatingCarrier="AR">
            <air:PassengerType Code="ADT" />
            <air:FlightOptionsList>
                <air:FlightOption LegRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BGNTVfDAAAA==" Destination="NQN" Origin="ROS">
                    <air:Option Key="5ScAI+BAAA/BSTTVfDAAAA==" TravelTime="P0DT14H20M0S">
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="K" BookingCount="7" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BwMTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BSMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="U" BookingCount="5" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/B2MTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BUMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:Connection SegmentIndex="0" />
                    </air:Option>
                </air:FlightOption>

                <air:FlightOption LegRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BKNTVfDAAAA==" Destination="ROS" Origin="NQN">
                    <air:Option Key="5ScAI+BAAA/BVTTVfDAAAA==" TravelTime="P0DT7H20M0S">
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="U" BookingCount="7" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/B3MTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BWMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="K" BookingCount="7" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BgNTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BYMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:Connection SegmentIndex="0" />
                    </air:Option>

                    <air:Option Key="5ScAI+BAAA/BYTTVfDAAAA==" TravelTime="P0DT17H0M0S">
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="U" BookingCount="7" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/B3MTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BWMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="K" BookingCount="7" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BgNTVfDAAAA==" SegmentRef="5ScAI+BAAA/BaMTVfDAAAA==" />
                        <air:Connection SegmentIndex="0" />
                    </air:Option>
                </air:FlightOption>
            </air:FlightOptionsList>

        </air:AirPricingInfo>
```

And the mapping function

```
final Map<String, List<Option>> segmentOptions =
 lowFareSearchRsp.getAirPricePointList().getAirPricePoint().stream()                 
 .flatMap(airPricePoint -> 
     airPricePoint.getAirPricingInfo().stream()
 )
 .filter(this::isAdultAirPricingInfo)
 .flatMap(airPricingInfo ->  
    airPricingInfo.getFlightOptionsList().getFlightOption().stream())
   .collect(
       groupingBy(
           flightOption -> flightOption.getOrigin() + flightOption.getDestination(),
           collectingAndThen(
                    mapping(
                      flightOption -> flightOption.getOption(), 
                      toList()
                    ),
                    lists -> lists.get(0)
          )
       )
  );
```

I would like to collect some data present in airPriceInfo and set it in a TemporalObject along with the grouping data return by the collect operation. Finally return a List of TemporalObject instead of a Map.

```
class TemporalObject {
    String platingCarrier;
    Map<String, List<Option>> segmentOptions;
}
```

Is this possible to do it with streams?
Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: Yes, it is. `collectingAndThen` can accept any collector, and there is an option to make custom collector from functions. However, it is not clear from  just the type of your summary object to say what that mighty map represents in the end.

Comment: You are not really grouping, when all you want is a single element for each group. Use `toMap(flightOption -> flightOption.getOrigin() + flightOption.getDestination(), flightOption -> flightOption.getOption())` instead of `groupingBy`. This will throw on duplicates. Use `toMap(flightOption -> flightOption.getOrigin() + flightOption.getDestination(), flightOption -> flightOption.getOption(), (a,b) -> a)` when you want to keep the behavior of using the first for each group and ignore all subsequent.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've added a piece of xml code as an example. i've already tried that but that is not what i need. I need to access some properties of the outer most object